# How can I replace ending of a string using regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string **`"http://www.something.com/test/?pt=12"`**

I want to replace `pt=12` by `pt=13` using regex.

The string after replace will be : **`"http://www.something.com/test/?pt=13"`**

How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: Unfortunately links are not working..

Comment: You could just use the [`String.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) method: `myStr.Replace("pt=12", "pt=13")`.

Comment: Spencer - I know the string.replace but actual requirmwent is quite complex.. I need a regex only. It's not a simple string replace.

Comment: If my answer was the answer you were looking for, could you please give it a check. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = "";
Regex reg = new Regex("(.*)(pt=12)");
Match regexMatch = reg.Match("http://www.something.com/test/?pt=12");
if(regexMatch.Success){
    result = regexMatch.Groups[1].Value + "pt=13"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you know the `pt=` part. I also presume that the param value is a number.

Then, you can use the following regex replacement:

```
var newval = 13;
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"\?pt=[0-9]+", string.Format("?pt={0}", newval));
```

If the param can be non-first in the query string, replace `\?` with `[?&]`.

Note that you could use the `System.UriBuilder` class. It has a `Query` property that you can use to rebuild the query string.